# Using bluetooth headphones in Debian

Tags: audio, debian, bluetooth, headphones

I installed Debian 10 today and so far am having a very positive experience.

However, as of right now, I'm having to use this laptop on speaker. This wouldn't be a problem, but I'm blind so everyone in the same room as my laptop will be able to hear my speech.

I have bluetooth headphones, Amazon's Echo buds to be exact. I'm trying to have them work with Debian.
I paired them up, no problem, using the blueman bluetooth manager.
They also report being connected, all fine so far.
But no sound from the headphones, it continues to play from the speaker, even when my sound dialogue insists that the headphones are the default output device.

I am using Mate Desktop Environment.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which program or programs are generating the sound?

Comment: This may be common problem with using **pulseaudio**, confirm if you are currently using  **pulseaudio** as your  sound server program.

Answer (score 0):

This may be common problem with **pulseaudio**, **pulseaudio** recognizes your Bluetooth device but  doesn't change all the audio sources to the connected Bluetooth device.
Make sure you have an updated version of sound server program by running `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`

Open **pulseaudio** from terminal by running `pavucontrol` and then select your Bluetooth device from the dropdown on **Port:** lable in the **Output Devices** tab.

**NB:** If this doesn't work for you just notify me on the comment section as you may also need to `kill` the **pulseaudio** deamon.